# Comparing a char in a struct to the user input

Tags: c, struct, user-controls

So while writing my code for some reason when comparing my char in a struct to the user input it doesn't pass as true when really it should be. Unless the user input is somehow not the same.

```
    struct user
{
    char login[11];

};

int main()
{
    char input_login[11];
    struct user goku;
    strcpy(goku.login,"goku");
    printf("Please enter the login:");
    fgets(input_login,11,stdin);

    printf("Please enter the password:");
    fgets(input_password,11,stdin);

    if (strcmp(goku.login, input_login) == 0) // not working
    {
        printf("correct");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s",goku.login);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets()` leaves the newline at the end of the string (if it read the whole line).  You need to either strip that off (replace it with a null char), or add a newline to the end of the string you're checking against -- then `strcmp()` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `fgets` places in the character array the new line character that corresponds to the pressed Enter key if there is enough space in the string.

You should remove this character.

For example

```
fgets(input_login,11,stdin);
input_login[strcspn( input_login, "\n" )] = '\0';
```